# How to make div dragable to each other in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="player-tab">
    <div class="img-wrap" draggable="true">
        <img src="assets/player.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="img-wrap" draggable="true">
        <img src="assets/player.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="add-recording"> <a href="#">+ Add Recording</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

In this code anyone can add recording and a player image show them after add. I want to img-wrap draggable to each other.

I means I upload 1 record and 2 record. I can sort it to 2nd first and 1st later. This way it's can be sorting in format as user want. Someone know any good idea to implement this feature.

Comment: So...you want to make a div draggable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#divid" ).draggable();
  });
```

see this:http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

I think you want this:

```
 $(function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
 });
```

check here:http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: [@Amrendra](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif) - Although he didn't say he wants jQuery, it is definitely reasonable to use it in this case.